# C: Execute a manually mmaped text segment without writing much assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mmap

## Problem:

I want to map a new (single page) text segment in memory and execute it without writing much of assembly, from a C program.
To do this, I am duplicating a C function of the program itself, and I am setting a flag so when I jump to it a different path in the function will be called.
You may think of it as stupid, but it's the same thing that we do when we, for example, `fork()` a process.

## Why

I have implemented a minimal capture and replay mechanism on Android, [link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02603).
Currently I am using a not so elegant way to replay real Android apps, which requires ASLR disabled, and apart from security holes (that for now could be simply ignored), it causes us some other issues.
So from a pure C process I want to make a transition and replay an Android function. If I make the following approach to work it will be much better that the current one, that intervenes on the first Android function that is called and belongs to the main thread, and .. bla bla..!

## Approach:

In a C program I am mapping a text segment, which basically is a copy of a C function of the program itself.
To do this, I am calling a function called `entrypoint` once, I get the program counter, set a flag and return.
Then, I mmap a page in memory (the code size of the entrypoint function shouldn't be larger that this) lets say at `0xabc000`, and I copy in it a page starting from the PC that I've got.
This means that page `abc` should contain a duplicate of the text/code from the pc to at least the end of the entrypoint function (a page starting from pc basically)
I set the permissions of page `abc`  to executable, and I jump to it.

And I get a segmentation violation. But I want to know, WHY?

## Example code:

```
bool entered_ = false;
void *pc_ = 0x0;

void entrypoint() {
if(!entered_){
entered = 1;
pc_ = GET_PROGRAM_COUNTER();
return;
}

// ..
// SPECIAL CODE
// ..

}

int main(..) {

entrypoint();
// map a new rdwr private page (4096)
newtextseg = mmap(..args..);

// copy 1 page of text from this application's text segment,
// starting from the point where I got the pc
memcpy(newtextseg, pc, PAGE_SIZE);

// give exec permissions to newtextseg
mprotect(..args);

// Jump to the code, and expect the
// SPECIAL CODE to run
JUMP(newtextseg);

}
```

## Extra information

The C library is statically linked with my application.
I run this on an Android device with arm architecture.
Unfortunately the OS does not give any info on the segmentation as it is a pure C process statically linked with libc. There is nothing that is Android related there. Not even `llog`.

## Assumptions

Assembly operations are correct (for getting and jumping to PC).
Also mmap and mprotect call outcomes are checked, and I verify by printing the `proc/self/maps` file.

## Random thoughts:

Since I am statically linked with libc, and I am doing some `printf`'s to the `entrypoint` for debugging purposes, it could be the case that the pointers to the functions have some fixed offset from the beginning of the original code segment (the one that I copied `entrypoint` from), so when I am trying to execute from a different offset things break?

Comment: You should at least compile as position independent code. To get the PC you can just use the function's name. If you get a segfault the bare minimum is that you use a debugger and show us where the fault is.

Comment: @Jester Unfortunately I am running this on an Android device and no event is generated by the OS for the `SEGV`. Not even a `tombstone` is created, which is what happens when a process crashes on Android.

Comment: I guess that I will have to test it to x86 with proper debugging and then transfer it on arm.

Comment: Why would `GET_PROGRAM_COUNTER();` in the middle of the function produce an address that is suitable to `memcpy()` a page-sized part of memory from? Why would the address have anything to to with the actual address of the function?

Comment: @EOF `memcpy` will just copy stuff from one position to another. Does it care what it will copy? As long as there is read access it does **not**. Why the downvote?

Comment: You really should motivate your question. Perhaps you want some JITing library (libjit, asmjit, GCCJIT, LLVM, ...)

Comment: You can only copy *from* a valid page. If the starting address is not page-aligned, and the page you `memcpy(...,...,PAGE_SIZE)` from is the last part of a `mmap()`ed region, you'll get a segfault for the `memcpy()` itself.

Comment: https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/selinux-mem.html

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch motivation added!

Comment: @EOF memcpy does not segfault. If it did, I would have padded a bit before and after the GET_PC and aligned. It also returns the destination address so I guess it handles everything okay!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a function pointer.

(I freely admit that this likely violates many parts of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)...)

First, `typedef` a function pointer type, since it's a lot easier to deal with function pointers if you use a `typedef`:

```
typedef ( *randomAddressFunc_t )( void );

// define a function pointer
randomAddressFunc_t JUMP;

// assign an address to the function pointer:
JUMP = ( randomAddressFunc_t ) newtextseg;

// call it
JUMP();
```

That should try to execute whatever binary bits are pointed to by `newtextseg`.

Comment: either by using function pointers, or by setting the program counter (as in my approach) it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned checking on x86, here is an example that worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

void printcaller()
{
    printf("caller = %p\n", __builtin_return_address(0));
}

void entrypoint(void (*callback)())
{
    callback();
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char* block = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    printf("entrypoint = %p, block = %p\n", entrypoint, block);
    memcpy(block, entrypoint, 1024);
    printf("entrypoint():");
    entrypoint(printcaller);
    printf("block():");
    ((void (*)())block)(printcaller);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./a.out
entrypoint = 0x40064a, block = 0x7eff7cbd1000
entrypoint():caller = 0x400661
block():caller = 0x7eff7cbd1017
```

Note I had to pass the callback address explicitly because a simple function call uses relative offset which breaks due to the copying. Accessing anything else (such as global data, including string literals) may also have this problem.

As @EOF mentioned in his comment:

> You can only copy from a valid page. If the starting address is not
>   page-aligned, and the page you memcyp(...,...,PAGE_SIZE) from is the
>   last part of a mmap()ed region, you'll get a segfault for the memcpy()
>   itself.

Indeed, I had to use 1024 exactly for this reason.

---

Alternate version passing function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

struct functions
{
    void* (*getcaller)();
    int (*printf)(const char*, ...);
};

void* getcaller()
{
    return __builtin_return_address(0);
}

void entrypoint(const char* fmt, const struct functions* functions)
{
    functions->printf(fmt, functions->getcaller());
}

int main()
{
    struct functions functions;
    unsigned char* block = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    printf("entrypoint = %p, block = %p\n", entrypoint, block);
    memcpy(block, entrypoint, 1024);
    functions.printf = printf;
    functions.getcaller = getcaller;
    entrypoint("entrypoint(): %p\n", &functions);
    ((void (*)())block)("block(): %p\n", &functions);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. It seems that I won't try on x86 as I am trying with a `remote gdb` server. I am not getting the `memcpy` error, so I am trying to investigate into it. Your approach jumps back to the original code though, whereas in my case I want to jump to an "independent" block of code! I can live without the data segment, but I will need access to library calls! If code pointers are broken my only hope is that `asm` calls do not go through `libc` internally..

Comment: I only jumped back so I could use the `__builtin_return_address` to get the caller's address which is of course the copied code. Just to show that it's the copied code executing. To access library calls you might have to pass them in a struct of function pointers.

Comment: Okay, I see. Still, I am setting directly the `pc` pointer (that's what `JMP` macro does in my example) which has an equivalent effect with yours.
The problem is that `entrypoint` still hangs. I will investigate it further and report back. `gdb` can't say much as it `cannot find bounds` of the copied function (as expected).

Comment: gdb doesn't need those bounds, you can nevertheless disassemble for example by doing `x/i $pc`